# How to remove zoom slider in UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to remove the zoom slider in the camera screen.
This is my code:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImagePickerController {
    class func sourceCameraModePhoto(_ delegate: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate, overlayView: UIView) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        picker.showsCameraControls = false
        picker.view.addSubview(overlayView)
        picker.delegate = delegate
        return picker
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess found the answer to this issue: 
The zoom slider is a UISlider, if your imagePickerController's view property contains a UISlider down its subviews, you can set its alpha to zero. This issue happens if you upgrade to iOS10.

```
func subviews(_ view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
    return view.subviews + view.subviews.flatMap { subviews($0) }
}

let myViews = subviews(imagePickerController.view)
for view in myViews {
    if view is UISlider {
        view.alpha = 0.0
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: Only works if you activate it inside the 'viewDidAppear' or later methods. 'viewDidLoad' or 'viewWillAppear' are not enough

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the zoom slider:

`picker.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

And it's probably future proof too.

The above knocks out user interaction for the camera.

Here is what worked for me finally.

Add the cameraOverlay as a subview to the picker.

```
if let overlay = overlayViewController?.view {
           imagePicker.view.addSubview(overlay)
        }
```

Comment: @Shiladitya  I've tried this, its just disables it but it doesn't remove/hide it.

Answer (score 0):

`showsCameraControls` should be set before the `UIImageViewController` is loaded.

That means you could it in the initialization of a customized `UIImageViewController`.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.showsCameraControls = false;
    }
    return self;
}
```