# How to remove the range slider of UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

There is a slider bar in my customized `UIImagePickerController`.
I've already removed the default camera controls and set a customized overlay view.

```
    self.showsCameraControls = false;
    self.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
```

But there is a range bar still on the view.
I can't find any related property or method to remove it.
[image]
[image]

Any advice will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.
Answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933460/how-to-remove-zoom-slider-in-uiimagepickercontroller) as well.

`showsCameraControls` should be set before the `UIImageViewController` is loaded.
That means you could do it in the initialization of your customized UIImageViewController.

```
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.showsCameraControls = false;

        self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Already answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933460/how-to-remove-zoom-slider-in-uiimagepickercontroller)

```
func subviews(_ view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
    return view.subviews + view.subviews.flatMap { subviews($0) }
}

let myViews = subviews(imagePickerController.view)
for view in myViews {
    if view is UISlider {
        view.alpha = 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought there is something more official I missed.